# Grafana 8 - slow performance loading dashboards

Tags: postgresql, performance, grafana, dashboard

I am having performance related issues since updating Grafana from version 7.5.7 to version 8.2.3.I have several large dashboards, that have more than around 200 panels and about 10ish variables. These large dashboards are now taking a very long time to load, several minutes, making the user experience quite poor when they would take a few seconds to load on the previous version.

I tried to investigate the dashboard’s webpage performance when opening one of them, and noticed that for the same dashboard:

- In version 7:

  - the activity Run Microtasks took 796ms
  - total blocking time = 2726ms
- In version 8:

  - the activity Run Microtasks took 8562ms
  - total blocking time = 9620ms

I couldn’t find in Grafana’s documentation what Grafana is doing differently with version, that would impact performance in the way described here, and if the issue is something that I can avoid.

Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-dashboards/#dashboard-is-slow

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, @JanGaraj !
I'd read that documentation before, but it didn't really help me understand what changed in version 8 to significantly lower dashboard loading performance, and how I can go back to previous performance.